# Autorun.inf - publisher not specified

Tags: windows-vista, autorun

I have the following autorun.inf

```
[Autorun]
action="Blah, Inc."
open=marketing.exe
icon=blah.ico
label="Blah, Inc."
```

On Vista, the autorun dialog shows "Publisher not specified".  How do I specify a publisher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bogdan is right: You need to sign your executable.
You can use *SignTool* from Microsoft for this. Taken from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387764.aspx):

> *SignTool tool is a command-line tool that digitally signs files, verifies signatures in files, or time stamps files. (...) The tool is installed in the \Bin folder of the Microsoft Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) installation path.
>   SignTool is available as part of the Windows SDK, which you can download as part of the Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5.*

Answer (score 2):

You specify the publisher by signing your executable file, not by writing it in the autorun.inf file.

How to do it...beats me, I'm a Java developer. Maybe someone else can tell you how.